# How to set default web browser

Tags: windows, uninstall, browser

I'm really annoyed when I uninstall a  program and then it opens up internet explorer.
Can I change this to a portable web browser?Or even prevent the uninstalled program to open up a web browser.

Comment: Uninstalled program opened up a web browser, or is it the uninstallation program that opened it up (like in those surveys "why did you uninstall our product?" and so on ?)

Comment: Which OS are you using, windows 7 or Xp?

Comment: @wag2639:7
@Idigas:the uninstaller opened it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7, theres a Default Programs menu for you to change your default program. Either search for "Default Programs" in the Start Menu or go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs`

In Windows XP, theres was something similar in the Start Menu (the exact name escapes me at the moment).

Also, many browsers will have a "Set as Default Browser" option, usually under "Tools" ... "Options".

However, it should be noted that some uninstallers hard code a reference to Internet Explorer to launch it by default instead of using your default browser.

Answer (score 2):

This question is titled 'How to set default web browser'.
Here's the answer I would use for an IE web browser assuming that's what browser you want (I'm using IE8.0.6).
Go to 'Tools' on the Menu Bar, Select 'Internet Options' (usually at bottom of list). Select 'Programs Tab'. Half way down that panel will be a section titled 'Default web browser'. Click the 'Make Default' soft button to set IE as default. You may also wish to select the Check Box to 'Tell me if Internet Explorer is not the default web browser.' Click 'OK' to effect change(s) and close the Internet Options panel or click 'Apply' to effect the change(s) without closing the Internet Options panel.

Other browsers generally provide a similar function to enable users to set THAT browser as the default and to also set a flag to notify you if that default setting has changed.

To prevent an uninstall /or install program from accessing the web, disable your internet connection temporarily before uninstalling. In XP I click Start > Connect To > Show all connections. Under the 'LAN or High-Speed Internet' heading, I select Local Area Connection, right-click and select Disable or select 'Disable this network device' in the Network Tasks panel at the left of the 'Network Connections' window.

The browser may still open when uninstalling software, which I agree is so irritating but it won't access the web. In my view it is also as irritating as when installing some software also often opens a browser and goes straight to some web page without the me being fore-warned of this. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default browser, but you can't guarantee the program doesn't have IE hard-coded as the browser to use.  What you can do is "break" internet explorer, so that it fails to start.  I wouldn't recommend this, though.  You'll find a lot programs make use of an embedded IE to show content within the program.